# Switching Between Fixed Orientations Mid Application - Android, AndEngine

Tags: java, android, andengine

Anyone here very well versed in using Android and the AndEngine game engine library?

What I am trying to do is change the screen orientation from Portrait, when on the menu screens, to Landscape when playing the game.

I currently have the game set up to use only one Android Activity and use several Scenes with a scene manager using AndEngine.

I currently can only chose one or the other regarding screen orientation. I know you can use the sensors to change the screen orientation too but I want to force the player into playing the game in Landscape and using the Menu's in Portrait.

Any ideas on how I would go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the build-in android function:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

While having this in your Manifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".Activity_name"
      android:configChanges="orientation">
```

To prevent your Game from getting restarted. You can catch those config changes with:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
       //do something
    }
    else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
       //do something        
    }
}
```

As described here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

I don't know if AndEngine will react kindly to this kind of change. The only other option in my mind would be to alter the `EngineOptions` which, to my knowledge, is not possible outside the `onLoadEngine` function.

The other obvious idea would be to just start a new `Activity` with a new `Engine` for the game itself.

Comment: Ya AndEngine doesn't seem to like it at all! Might just have to use 2 Activities.

Comment: Mind marking my answer as correct? So users will now what "solved" ur problem.